Gas furnace short cycling during recovery (after air temperature is above thermostat setting)
Tempstar Gas Furnace
Model: NUG5075BFB1
Age: appr. 28 years old
This is the upstairs gas furnace, which is also the air handler for the AC unit. This year when the upstairs furnace was switched from AC to heat, it ran fine and heated the area as intended.
Recently we noticed that the upstairs unit would complete the heat cylce, then after a short period, the inducer fan motor would kick on and run for a few seconds, then kick off. After a few more seconds this cycle would repeat.
First note
When the thermostat called for heat (air temp < thermostat setting), the furnace went through the start up routine and fired up without any issues whatsoever.
Second note
Once the air temp was at or higher than the thermostat (air temp > thermostat), the furnace would shut off and go into the recover mode - for a while.  Shortly after this, the inducer fan motor would begin short cycling again - but did not attempt to continue the heat sequence (ignite, etc).
What I have done:

I have two identical programmable thermostats in my home (upstairs and downstairs). Both thermostats use batteries as source for power and batteries have been replaced with no change in condition.
I switched the thermostats and found that after switching them, the upstairs continued the inducer short cycling problem and the downstairs exhibited no problems using the thermostat from the upstairs (problematic) HVAC.
Based upon this I assumed that the thermostat itself was not the issue since the problem occurred on the same upstairs furnace with a different (but identical) thermostat taken from the downstairs unit, and the problem did not occur on the downstairs furnace using the upstairs thermostat.
I disconnected the two wires going to the single pressure sensor switch completely.  With the wires disconnected, the inducer fan motor will turn on and begin the short cycle (without proceeding to the next sequence action / ignite).  When I run a jumper wire between these two wire while disconnected, the inducer motor will turn off immediately.  Once I disconnect the jumper wire, the inducer motor will go back on again.  I have not tried monitoring either condition for more than a minute.

PLEASE UNDERSTAND that the inducer short cycle is NOT at the beginning of the heat start up sequence (the heat sequence and cycle appears to be working correctly) - but ONLY after the furnace heat sequence has started properly, heated to thermostat temp setting, then turns off to standby/recovery mode (air temp > thermostat setting).
I have read potential issues that may cause this including:

faulty pressure sensor switch (although I do not understand how the pressure switch could do this since it's job is to respond to the inducer fan's creation of a negative pressure, and hence is technically "behind" the inducer fan initiation part of the heating sequence.  Is there some signal from the pressure switch that causes a response from the inducer motor?)
inducer fan motor capacitor issue
inducer fan motor issue
control board issue
gremlins, etc.

I understand the basic steps in the heat sequence and it seems that the short cycling (during the recovery mode) only involves the inducer motor kicking on (for a period of time). As long as the air temp > thermostat setting, that's as far as it goes (no igniter stage, no gas release, no blower motor, etc).
I have found several discussions about the inducer short cycling, but most are related to a short cycle problem at the beginning of the heat cycle sequence (when air temp < thermostat).
I appreciate any diagnostic suggestions or advice on what may be the cause of this problem. Thank you.

Welcome. Please take the [tour].

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
